# Get Common elements and Difference between two Lists by a particular property using Streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have two lists of objects `dbAssets` and `assetVOS`.

I want **common** elements (and **difference**) by some property (`getSecName()` in my case) using streams.

I've tried the following:

```
dbAssets.stream().map(SomeClass::getSecName)
    .filter(dbAssetName -> assetVOS.stream()
            .map(SomeClass::getSecName)
            .anyMatch(assetVOSName -> dbAssetName.equals(assetVOSName)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Incompatible types. Required `List<SomeClass>` but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that `String` conforms to `SomeClass` inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: `SomeClass` lower bounds `String`

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use streams? IMHO, using good old loops would result in a much more readable solution than your approach. If you want to stick with streams, improve the readability (and error spotting) by breaking up the long streams method chain, introducing variables for the intermediate streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are mapping your `SomeClass` instances into `String`s, your stream pipeline produces a `List<String>`, not a `List<SomeClass>`.

To get a `List<SomeClass>`, try something like this:

```
List<SomeClass> output = 
    dbAssets.stream()
            .filter(obj -> assetVOS.stream()
                                   .map(SomeClass::getSecName)
                                   .anyMatch(assetVOSName -> obj.getSecName ().equals(assetVOSName)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want **common** elements (and **difference**)

If you want both: a list of elements with the second name is property which present in the `assetVOS` list and a list of those elements which names are not are not present, you can use *collector* [`partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)) to do that in one iteration over the `dbAssets` list.

And instead of iterating over the list `assetVOS` multiple times to check if it contains an element with a particular name, we can store all the names from the `assetVOS` into a set, and then perform the checks against the set in a constant time.

That how it might look like:

```
List<SomeClass> dbAssets = // initializing the list
List<SomeClass> assetVOS = // initializing the list
        
Set<String> names = assetVOS.stream()
    .map(SomeClass::getSecName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
Map<Boolean, List<SomeClass>> presentInAssetVOS = dbAssets.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
        user -> names.contains(user.getSecName())
    ));
    
List<SomeClass> isPresentInAssetVOS = presentInAssetVOS.get(true);
List<SomeClass> notPresentInAssetVOS = presentInAssetVOS.get(false);
```